# Merge sort in C++ - strange behavior of a program

Tags: c++, mergesort

Update: modified condition in the merge function, now everything works fine

I'm trying to implement a merge sort algorithm in c++ which works with intege vectors. So here is my piece of code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Vout (vector <int> V){
    for (int i = 0; i<V.size(); i++)
        cout << V[i] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}

vector <int> merge (vector <int> B, vector <int> C){
    vector <int> D;
    int n = B.size() + C.size();
    int i=0, j=0;

    for (int k = 0; k<n; k++){
        if( ( B[i]<C[j] || j == C.size() ) && i<B.size() ){  //was like this: if( B[i]<C[j] ){
            D.push_back(B[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            D.push_back(C[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    return D;
}

vector <int> merge_sort(vector <int> A){
    int n = A.size();
    if (n<=1) return A;
    vector <int> B, C;
    for (int i = 0; i<n/2; i++)
        B.push_back(A[i]);
    for (int i = n/2; i<n; i++)
        C.push_back(A[i]);

    B = merge_sort(B);
    C = merge_sort(C);
    vector <int> D = merge(B, C);
    return D;
}


int main() {
    vector <int> data;
    freopen("input.txt", "rt", stdin);
    int n;
    while (cin >> n){
        data.push_back(n);}
    Vout (data);
    Vout (merge_sort(data));
}
```

However with this input

> 5 4   6   7   9   1   2   8   3   12  10

it gives the following output:

> 1 2   3   0   4   5   6   7   8   9   0

I don't quite understand where all these zeroes came from. Please help.

Comment: your problem is in merge function , don't let i or j be grater then size of vector

Comment: Thanks! indeed that was a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `merge()` function doesn't handle running off the end of the `B` or `C` vectors; when it reaches the end of either, your comparison (`B[i]<C[j]`) will be comparing against one past the end of the array.

Comment: Sure, but still need to wait 6 minutes to accept. You answered too fast :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the merge function as given below and it worked.

```
vector <int> merge (vector <int> B, vector <int> C){
    vector <int> D;
    int n = B.size() + C.size();
    int i=0, j=0;

    for (int k = 0; k<n; k++){
        if(B[i]<C[j]){
            D.push_back(B[i]);
            i++;

            if(i == B.size())
                break;
        }
        else{
            D.push_back(C[j]);
            j++;

            if(j == C.size())
                break;
        }
    }

    if(i == B.size())
    {
        while(j < C.size())
            D.push_back(C[j++]);
    }

    if(j == C.size())
    {
        while(i < B.size())
            D.push_back(B[i++]);

    }
    return D;
}
```